# Git log find current branch

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Can I get git log from specific branch ? example I can get git log from master branch

by using this this command

> git log -10 --no-merges refs/remotes/origin/master

but if I need log from current branch (`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`) How can I achieve that

Comment: If you don't specify the branch, `git log` uses the current branch.

Comment: How can I get Pull Request  branch?

Comment: Pull requests aren't branches. In fact, *GIt* doesn't have pull requests at all. Pull requests are add-ons, provided by GitHub, Bitbucket, and GitLab for instance (but GitLab don't call theirs "pull requests"). To get more information about pull requests, pick the hosting system—the details depend on that—and then ask that question. The question you've asked here is about providing arguments to `git log`, which is mostly answered directly by the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

if i get your question you can go to the specific branch using `git branch`  then you can get the log using `git log`